# xslt permutations adding commas and 'and'

Tags: xslt, permutation, combinations

I'll rephrase entire question because I nearly have the solution and my question was badly constructed:

I have the code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="documentarycredits/documentarycreditdata">
    <xsl:if test="tradetypes/option[@id='tradefinguar']='selected'">Trade Finance Guarantee</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="tradetypes/option[@id='tradefinstand']='selected'">Trade Finance Standby Letters of Credit serving as Financial Guarantees</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="tradetypes/option[@id='tradefindoc']='selected'">Trade Finance Documentary Credits</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()=last()-1">
        <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

which seems to work well apart from it has ', and' e.g. 'A, and B' .

Ideally I'd like A and B and anything else can have E.G. A, B, C and F

I'd like to apply the same even when I have a dropdown of 20 values.

Thanks

edit for comment on JLRish & Tim C answer:

```
            <tradetypes>
            <option id="tradefinguar">selected</option>
            <option id="tradefinstand"/>
            <option id="tradefindoc"/>
        </tradetypes>
```

There are a number of individual xslt screens so its possible that more than three of the above can be select which would result in multiples e.g. A, A, B, C, A and B but ideally I'd like it to know if one has been selected already only produce it once.

Comment: maybe xsl-if is better to use

Comment: Could you provide the relevant portion of your input XML? And what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I've added this now to question. I'm close to getting it but needs a tweak I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, is make us of template matching. First select **option** elements which have been selected

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="tradetypes/option[. = 'selected']"/>
```

Then you have a template that matches **option** elements where you first output either a comma or "and" based on the position

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="position() &gt; 1 and position() = last()"> and </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
```

When, you have a simple **xsl:choose** to output A,B or C

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="@id='tradefinguar'">A</xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="@id='tradefinstand'">B</xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="@id='tradefindoc'">C</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tradetypes/option[. = 'selected']"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="option">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="position() &gt; 1 and position() = last()"> and </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@id='tradefinguar'">A</xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="@id='tradefinstand'">B</xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="@id='tradefindoc'">C</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When used on the following XML, the output is `A`

```
<tradetypes>
   <option id="tradefinguar">selected</option>
   <option id="tradefinstand"/>
   <option id="tradefindoc"/>
</tradetypes>
```

When used on the following XML, the output is `A and B`

```
<tradetypes>
   <option id="tradefinguar">selected</option>
   <option id="tradefinstand">selected</option>
   <option id="tradefindoc"/>
</tradetypes>
```

When used on the following XML, the output is `A, B and C`

```
<tradetypes>
   <option id="tradefinguar">selected</option>
   <option id="tradefinstand">selected</option>
   <option id="tradefindoc">selected</option>
</tradetypes>
```

Comment: Definitely the best solution. This worked in my case <xsl:if test="position()!=last() and position()!=last()-1">
                     <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="position()=last()-1">
                     <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                     <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                   </xsl:if>

Comment: @Tim C Sorry Tim, could I ask one more question. Someone can potentially pick 5 of the above options so it could be A, A, B, B and C. I want it to be so if they are selected once it will not repeat them and for one special 'other' freetext box that it would repeat this. e.g. A, B, other1, other2 and C or other1, A,other2 and C or something similar. Not sure if possible.

Comment: Hmmm.... Perhaps it would be better to ask a whole new question? There is nothing wrong with asking a new question that follows on from a previous one, but just make sure the new question can be answered in isolation from the previous one. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C thanks. new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464556/xslt-ordering-list-and-if-multiples-only-print-word-once

Answer (score 1):

Going off your updated XSLT, I think the following change would do it:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="documentarycredits/documentarycreditdata">
    <xsl:for-each select="tradetypes/option[. = 'selected']">
      <xsl:if test="@id='tradefinguar'">Trade Finance Guarantee</xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@id='tradefinstand'">Trade Finance Standby Letters of Credit serving as Financial Guarantees</xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@id='tradefindoc'">Trade Finance Documentary Credits</xsl:if>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() + 1 = last()">
          <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="last() > 1 and position() != last()">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks. I did <xsl:if test="position()!=last() and position()!=last()-1"> <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> </xsl:if> <xsl:if test="position()=last()-1"> <xsl:text> and </xsl:text> </xsl:if> <xsl:if test="position()=last()"> <xsl:text></xsl:text> </xsl:if> which works aswell but yours is tidier :)

Comment: Sorry JL, could I ask one more question. Someone can potentially pick 5 of the above options so it could be A, A, B, B and C. I want it to be so if they are selected once it will not repeat them and for one special 'other' freetext box that it would repeat this. e.g. A, B, other1, other2 and C or other1, A,other2 and C or something similar. Not sure if possible.

Comment: So they could select the same option multiple times? Could you show in your question above what that would look like in the input XML?  Also show how the freetext items would be represented in the input XML.

Comment: I've updated now. the other box is a free text box <producttypes>
    <option id="domguar">selected</option>
    <option id="indemnity"/>
    <option id="domcontbond"/>
    <option id="perfbond"/>
    <option id="interventionguar"/>
    <option id="customsguar"/>
    <option id="vatbond"/>
    <option id="otherprodtype"/>
   </producttypes>
   <otherprodtypebox/>

Comment: so ideally if one of A, B, C, D, E, F, G are selected it will only print out one but if multiple others...it will print out all the others e.g. A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, H, H, H and H

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete sample (in your question) that demonstrates the duplicates and free text items.  I agree with Tim C that it might make sense to start a new question.

Comment: thanks. new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464556/xslt-ordering-list-and-if-multiples-only-print-word-once