# xslt ordering list and if multiples only print word once

Tags: list, xslt

I have the following dropdown

```
<xsl:if test="bankguarantee!=0">
            <li style="font-family:Arial,Arial MT,Luxi Sans,Verdana; font-size:10pt; margin:0cm 0cm 0pt; ">
                <p style="font-family:Arial,Arial MT,Luxi Sans,Verdana; font-size:10pt; margin:0cm 0cm 0pt; ">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial,Arial MT,Luxi Sans,Verdana; font-size:11.0pt; ">The terms and conditions of <xsl:if test="bankguarantee='1'">the </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="bankguarantee!='1'">each </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="bankguarantees/bankguaranteedata">
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='A']='selected'">A</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='B']='selected'">B</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='C']='selected'">C</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='D']='selected'">D</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='E']='selected'">E</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='F']='selected'">F</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='G']='selected'">G</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='H']='selected'"><xsl:value-of select="otherprodtypebox"/></xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position()!=last() and position()!=last()-1">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()-1">
    <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
  </xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

and the following xml

```
<producttypes>
                <option id="A">selected</option>
                <option id="B"/>
                <option id="C"/>
                <option id="D"/>
                <option id="E"/>
                <option id="F"/>
                <option id="G"/>
                <option id="H"/>
            </producttypes>
        <otherprodtypebox/>
```

Basically all works ok at the moment but I want to avoid multiples occurring and to put all the other boxes at the end. There can be 99 of these screens.

At the moment say I select 5 options I could get A, B, B, otherbox and otherbox

I want it to have if A is selected more than once only display A and the same for all letters to G

The issue comes with the other box at H which can have multiples

so you could have

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, H, H, H AND H

I hope this makes sense and any solutions very much appreciated.

N.B. Important to note the XML is created for each screen so I could have 99 different XMLs with something different selected everytime. this is where the for-each part is tricky. maybe it can detect if more than 1 of A is selected. thanks

Comment: Could you show what's before and after the `<xsl:for-each>`?  Perhaps the whole `<xsl:template>` that contains it? Does the XML contain multiple `bankguarantees` or multiple `bankguaranteedata`s?  The information you've been providing has been rather lacking.  Have you produced a situation where your current approach produces duplicate letters in the output?

Comment: @JLRishe I've added this now. The whole template is 20000 lines of code I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this near the top of the XSLT file:

```
<xsl:key name="productOption" match="producttypes/option[. = 'selected']" use="@id"/>
```

and replacing your `for-each` loop with this `for-each` loop:

```
  <xsl:for-each 
   select="bankguarantees/bankguaranteedata/producttypes/option[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('productOption', @id)[1]) or @id = 'H']">
    <xsl:sort select="count(preceding-sibling::option)" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'A'">A</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'B'">B</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'C'">C</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'D'">D</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'E'">E</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'F'">F</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'G'">G</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@id = 'H'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../otherprodtypebox"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last() and position()!=last()-1">
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()-1">
      <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

When run on this input:

```
<bankguarantees>
  <bankguaranteedata>
    <producttypes>
      <option id="A">selected</option>
      <option id="B"/>
      <option id="C"/>
      <option id="D"/>
      <option id="E"/>
      <option id="F"/>
      <option id="G"/>
      <option id="H"/>
    </producttypes>
    <otherprodtypebox>sprockets</otherprodtypebox>
  </bankguaranteedata>
  <bankguaranteedata>
    <producttypes>
      <option id="A">selected</option>
      <option id="B"/>
      <option id="C"/>
      <option id="D">selected</option>
      <option id="E"/>
      <option id="F"/>
      <option id="G"/>
      <option id="H">selected</option>
    </producttypes>
    <otherprodtypebox>widgets</otherprodtypebox>
  </bankguaranteedata>
  <bankguaranteedata>
    <producttypes>
      <option id="A">selected</option>
      <option id="B">selected</option>
      <option id="C"/>
      <option id="D">selected</option>
      <option id="E"/>
      <option id="F"/>
      <option id="G"/>
      <option id="H">selected</option>
    </producttypes>
    <otherprodtypebox>cogs</otherprodtypebox>
  </bankguaranteedata>

</bankguarantees>
```

Produces this output:

```
A, B, D, widgets and cogs
```

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe I'll try this out in the morning and will let you know. Much appreciated

Comment: Hats off. Works a charm and I learnt a great deal too with this brilliant explanation.

Comment: can I have another xsl key e.g. <xsl:key name="tradeOption" match="tradetypes/option[. = 'selected']" use="@id"/> on the one page? as I need to do this for another drop down and its saying my xml isnt well formed :( . thanks

Comment: @topcat3 Yes, you can add as many keys as you like, but depending on your specific objective, there could be more and less elegant ways to approach it.  Perhaps you could open a separate question referencing this one and elaborating on your additional requirements?

Comment: thanks. new q here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649715/xslt-numbering-and-ordering . It should be straightforward as I don't even have the other box this time. maybe you can see something I can't :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicates goes generally under the name "grouping", and if you look up grouping in the index of your favourite XSLT textbook you will find plenty of information.

There are nice solutions for this in XSLT 2.0, and ugly solutions in XSLT 1.0, so the answer depends very much on which version you are using, which you haven't said.